# how to select all file inputs starts with certian text in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to select all file inputs that starts with `image_`, likely to this `$names = $request->input('products.*.name');` but I've tried this on inputs starting with `ex_` returned null.

also I can't see the image in the `request`, if so I can do a quick solution like foreach in pure php or something

Comment: are you trying to upload multiple files with the same name like `images[]` or different names?

Comment: I am not sure about multiple file selector with regex but did you try with `request()->all()` or `request()->file()` ?

Comment: @sachinKumar no, the names is `image_` plus a random 9 charecters, my form don't work with `images[]`, even if it works it very hard to edit, let me try your solutions

Comment: I think you can run `request()->all()` which include text as well as the file input. Then all you need to filter from the request array whose key is start with `image_`

Comment: I can't see the inputs start with image I dont know what's going on if you need any extra details tell me, please help me I'm stuck I have to finish the project in 1 FEB